# how to move to first upper c line of disassembly eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, arm, stm32, disassembly

I am trying to debug/disassembly code of STM32F411 Discovery board in Eclipse. When I am moving to specific program counter location, it shows me assembler line. Instead of assembly line, I would like to move to the first C code that triggered execution of that line. For example in Eclipse disassembly view:

```
 96           GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;
080007ac:   mov.w   r3, #512        ; 0x200
080007b0:   str     r3, [sp, #4]
 97           GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
```

Where 96 is number of the line that triggered execution of assembler at position of `080007ac` and `080007b0`. So I am looking for a way to move from `080007b0` to 96. Usually it is easy to scroll if there are few lines of code, but in my specific situation there are like 10000 lines (or more) of assembler code preceding C line, so it is difficult for me to find which C line triggered error.

Comment: Any decent debugger should have the option to show C and asm mixed. Eclipse is infamous for it's poor debugger, which is particularly horrible for microcontroller applications. I would strongly recommend to get an Eclipse-free tool chain for embedded systems.

Comment: @Lundin eclipse has a very decent debugger. I use it for years and I almost only work on the embedded projects. You know who blames his tools.

Comment: BTW eclipse debugger allows mixed view and debug

Comment: @P__J__ Whereas I have worked with at least ten debuggers over the past ten years and find the Eclipse one to be inferior to pretty much everything else on the market, just like the IDE itself.

Comment: @Lundin you may not like the eclipse. I have worked as well using many and actually the eclipse is one of best (in a proper hands of course).

Comment: @P__J__ Try Crossworks, IAR, Lauterbach, iSystem, pretty much any commercial debugger out there.

Comment: I also have used eclipse and find it fine.  No better or worse than any other (free) tool, just different.  The debugger is gdb really of course, eclipse just offers a frontend.  But I have always had a working split C / disassembly view and source stepping has always worked fine, so I'm not sure why OP has the problem that they have...